# Случайный сундук, поиск параметров

Tags: алгоритм, математика, теория-вероятностей

Всем привет! Я делаю рулетку для одного учебного проекта. Так, вот у меня есть кейс с ценой в **59₽**, в нём расположены предметы:

```
1 — 10₽ 
2 — 30₽
3 — 50₽
4 — 60₽
5 — 80₽
6 — 100₽
7 — 140₽
8 — 200₽
9 — 250₽
10 — 400₽
11 — 600₽
12 — 1000₽
13 — 1500₽
14 — 2500₽
```

Как мне найти связь между ценой предметов, ценой кейса и количеством предметов и правильно распределить шанс выпадения для каждого предмета? Я пытался играться с числами и составить какую-нибудь формулу, но у меня ничего не получается и я не знаю как это можно правильно посчитать, чтобы процент выпадения каждого предмета зависел от его цены и от цены кейса.

Comment: я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Igor есть кейс с ценой 59 рублей. Нужно составить формулу, которая высчитывает шанс выпадения для каждого предмета, учитывая цену кейса, цену предмета и количество предметов в самом кейсе.

Comment: Что здесь такое кейс? Как он связан с рулеткой?

Comment: Я все равно ничего не понял. И не я один.

Comment: @MBo кейс — сундук, где расположены вещи. Из сундука, при открытии, может выпасть одна вещь. Сундук стоит 59 рублей, цена вещей написана в условии. Мне нужно распределить шанс равномерно между 14 предметами, учитывая цену сундука, чтобы если менялась цена сундука, то и менялись проценты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Анализ задачи с точки зрения теории вероятностей.

Есть кейс, при открывании которого случайно выпадает один из предметов `1..N` (в вашем случае `N = 14`). Обозначим цены предмета `c1, ... , cN`, обозначим вероятности выпадения `p1, ... , pN`, `p1 + ... + pN = 1`.

Стоимости предметов `ck` известны, нужно найти вероятности `pk` (при заданной общей стоимости кейса, обозначим это стоимость через `V`).

Посчитаем математическое ожидание цены предмета, который мы достаём из кейса, это легко:

```
EV := E{cost} = p1*c1 + ... + pN*cN
```

Нам нужно, чтобы математическое ожидание цены не превышало цены кейса (иначе в среднем игрок с открытия кейсов получит больше, чем заплатил за них, что невыгодно для игры). Отсюда получаем условие:

```
EV <= V
```

Будем считать, что мы честные, и поставим выше равенство, то есть это будет означать, что игра не имеет ни прибыли, ни убытков от продаже кейсов (если вы хотите, после расчётов вы можете взять цену V больше расчётной, и игра будет иметь прибыль, или же меньше, тогда игроки будут иметь прибыль).

Мы имеем уравнение:

```
V = p1*c1 + ... + pN*cN
```

Оно не имеет однозначного решения. Поэтому добавим дополнительные требования. Допустим, у нас 2 предмета, один в 2 раза дороже другого, тогда было бы логично, если бы более дорогой выпадал бы в 2 раза реже того, что дешевле, то есть дешёвый должен выпадат с вероятностью 2/3, а дорогой с вероятностью 1/3. Отсюда логично напрашивается вывод, что вероятности должны быть обратно пропорциональны ценности предметов:

```
p_i = K * (1/c_i)
```

Добавляем условие нормировки вероятностей:

```
1 = p1 + ... + pN = K * [(1/c1) + ... + (1/cN)]
```

откуда:

```
K = 1 / [(1/c1) + ... + (1/cN)]
```

среднее гармоническое цен предметов.

Заметим, что эти условия уже полностью определили вероятности, и из уравнения выше мы можем вычислить значение цены кейса `V`, которую необходимо назначить, чтобы не было ни прибыли, ни убытков. Это означает, что заранее выбрать цену `V` вообще говоря нельзя.

Решить эту проблему можно частично, если добавить ещё выпадение предмета нулевой ценности, с вероятностью `p0` и ценой `c0 = 0`, тогда коэффициент `K` определяется из уравнение совпадения математического ожидания цены кейса с реальной ценой `V = EV`:

```
V = p1*c1 + ... + pN*cN
V = K*N
K = V/N
```

Теперь суммируем вероятности `p_i = K*(1/c_i) = V/(N*c_i)`:

```
p1 + ... + pN = (V/N) * ( (1/c1) + ... + (1/cN) )
```

и эта сумма должна не превышать единицы, чтобы можно было дополнить её неотрицательной вероятностью `p0, которая будет отвечать за выпадения условного игрового мусора, то есть:

```
(V/N) * ( (1/c1) + ... + (1/cN) ) < 1
```

откуда получаем ограничение на допустимую заранее назначенную цену кейса `V`:

```
V <= N * (1 / ( (1/c1) + ... + (1/cN) ) )
```

и тогда

```
p0 = 1 - (V/N) * ( (1/c1) + ... + (1/cN) )
```

### Выводы и формулы.

1. Если заранее заданы ценности предметов в кейсе, то цену кейса `V` и вероятности выпадения предметов `p_i` можно определить по формулам:

   ```
   K   = 1 / [(1/c1) + ... + (1/cN)]
   V   = N*K
   p_i = K * (1/c_i)
   ```
2. Если же цена кейса `V` задана заранее, то следует ввести вероятность `p0` выпадение предмета, не представляющего игровой ценности, и вероятности будут определяться по следующим формулам:

   ```
   K   = V/N
   p_i = K * (1/c_i)
   p0  = 1 - (V/N) * ( (1/c1) + ... + (1/cN) )
   ```

   и возможно это лишь при условии выполненного неравенства:

   ```
   V <= N * (1 / ( (1/c1) + ... + (1/cN) ) )
   ```

Comment: Ого, спасибо вам огромное! Это как раз то, что нужно, но у меня только непонимание с второй формулой, когда можно выставлять цену кейса самому. Мне к этим 14 предметам нужно будет добавить ещё один (пятнадцатый) предмет p0, который будет иметь цену 0 и в случае его выпадения мне нужно делать перевыбор предмета. Или как это должно работать? Извиняюсь сразу за возможно глупый вопрос.

Comment: Да, вам нужно сделать ещё вероятность, что из сундука не выпадет вообще ничего (или некий 15-й предмет, который не представляет ценности). Перевыбор вам делать не нужно, просто в случае выпадения этого бесполезного предмета (или в случае, если сундук оказался пустым), игрок остаётся с носом, и получает фигу с маслом :) Ну типа вы открыли сундук, а там ничего полезного, только обглоданный скелет селёдки) Из соображений некой лояльности к игрокам, лучше обглоданный скелет селёдки, чем просто вариант с пустым сундуком, это не так негативно будет восприниматься...

Comment: Если что-то неясно - спрашивайте, я математические темы люблю, с удовольствием разъясню) Глупых вопросов не существует, бывает лишь глупые ответы ("сделайте за меня" вопросом не считается :) )

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо вам большое за ответ! То есть всё-таки такого варианта не существует, где процент выпадения между предметами распределялся равномерно, в зависимости от цены кейса (сундука)?

К примеру:
Цена кейса — 50 рублей
Вещи в нём:
1 — 10 руб. (30%)
2 — 25 руб. (25%)
3 — 40 руб. (20%)
4 — 50 руб. (15%)
5 — 65 руб. (10%)

Если цену кейса повысить до 65 рублей, то:
1 — 10 руб. (10%)
2 — 25 руб. (25%)
3 — 40 руб. (30%)
4 — 50 руб. (20%)
5 — 65 руб. (15%)

Я написал примерные проценты, но я надеюсь, что вы суть поняли.

Comment: чтобы вам удобнее было читать: https://pastebin.com/LjWGKYFy

Comment: Да, варианта, когда цена сундука задана изначально не существует (если мы хотим баланса), хак с p0 это хак, потому что сама идея невыпадения предметов не вписывается в модель, когда вероятность выпадения обратно пропорциональна ценности (тогда p0 должно было бы равняться бесконечности). Мой вариант решения не единственный, я базировался на идее, что в два раза более ценный предмет должен выпадать в два раза реже. Если мы её принимаем, то вероятности становятся определены, и стоимость сундука уже вычисляется, а не задаётся.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. И последний вопрос, можно ли как-то равномерно уменьшить (или увеличить) предмет каждого шанс на 10/20/30%, чтобы в сумме оставалось 100%?

Comment: И можно связаться с вами в Telegram?

Comment: Вероятность (шанс) это такая величина, которая должна удовлетворять условию нормировки - сумма всех вероятностей равна 1, если мы как-то уменьшим все вероятности, то сумма станет меньше 1, аналогично если увеличим. Это означает, что равномерно все уменьшить или увеличить нельзя. Телегой не пользуюсь, пишите на почту: blackzabeth@yandex.ru

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, стоит сделать, своего рода, "систему ценностей", то есть понять, сколько стоит дорогая вещи в эквиваленте дешёвой, сопоставить всё между собой, и запустить рандомайзей. Далее можно попробовать реализовать что-то такое:

```py
import random

  #Тут я просто написал рандомные числа, 
  #вам придётся самому просчитывать нужный шанс выпадения:
  #специальным алгоритмом, или "на бумажке" 
Variant = [50, 90, 120, 140, 150, 155, ...] 

a = random.randint(1, 150)
for i in range(len(Variant)):
    if a <= Variant[i]:
        print('Вам выпал предмет:' + str(i + 1))
        break
```

Правда, список можно будет заменить на словарь ( {1: 50, 2: 90, ...}

Comment: Я уже пытался подобное делать, но перебирать большим количеством If-ов не самый лучший вариантов.

Comment: @nikitafrolov12, а разве 15(в вашем случае) if-ов, это много, по моему, это самый надёжный способ. Я бы сделал, например, числа от 1 до 500 - первый объект, затем числа от 501 до, скажем, 800 - второй объект, и т.д. В зависимости от экивалентов, о которых я писал выше, разумеется)

Comment: у меня могут быть другие виды сундуков, с разными вещами и для них их тоже такую проверку по 15 if-ов делать точно не вариант. Нужно какое-то оптимальное решение/формула, которое будет подходить под все виды.

Comment: @nikitafrolov12, тогда могу только предложить как-то поиграть с остатками, или чем-то в этом роде. Больше идей нет, извините.